# Find entries via substring regex query in mongodb-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I can't get the official go mongo driver to successfully return objects that are queried via a regex query.

I already know how to do it via the mongo shell and get my expected results.
With this example i get all entries that contain "he" in their 'text' field:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"text": /he/})
```

same with this one:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"text": {$regex: /he/, $options: ''}})
```

This is my current code that doesn't work:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(5*time.Second))
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    db := client.Database("test")
    coll := db.Collection("test")

    filter := bson.D{{"text", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "/he/", Options: ""}}}
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cur, err := coll.Find(ctx, filter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    i := 0
    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        i = i + 1
    }
    fmt.Println("Found", i, "elements")
}
```

Per [example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/51421e413403fe3c9b0097147841f752421133e4/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go#L293) in the official mongo-go-driver repository, this should work.

My current entries in the collection just contain 2 fields, the id field and an extra text field. I currently have 3 entries. that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cc7e9950198ceeefecbdd"),
    "text" : "hello world"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cc7f6950198ceeefecbec"),
    "text" : "hello"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9cc804950198ceeefecbfa"),
    "text" : "test world"
}
```

My expected results with the code from above, should be the first 2 entries. Instead i get an empty cursor back.

Does anybode know, what i am doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`primitive.Regex` struct accepts `Pattern` value without slashes, so it must be:

```
filter := bson.D{{"text", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "he", Options: ""}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: filter := bson.D{{"text", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "he", Options: "i"}}} add i value in Options for case sensitive lowercase or uppercase pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

- . -> matches any character
- *-> matches zero of more occurrence of previous character
  So below filter will give you all results which has "he" as substring

`filter = bson.M{"text": primitive.Regex{Pattern: ".*" + "he" + ".*", Options: "i"}}`

Comment: `Pattern: "he"` will also match all substrings